# elasticsearch nest 7.1 aggregation Fields generic shorthand field expression

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-aggregation

so reading this:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/7.x/field-inference.html

given a class of

```
public class MyData {
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
}
```

I would expect to be able to do something like:

```
var fieldExpression = Field<MyData >(p => p.Value);
```

but I get an error of `The non-generic type Field cannot be used with type arguments`.

I am using Nest 7.1.0.

My goal was to be able to create a method that can have aggregations and queries passed in and then combined into running on a instance of a nest `ElasticClient`.

something like (I think)

```
            var sr = new SearchRequest<MyData>
            {
                Aggregations = new ChildrenAggregation("name_of_child_agg", typeof(decimal?))
                {
                    Aggregations =
                        new AverageAggregation("average_per_child", Field<MyData>(p => p.value))
                        && new MaxAggregation("max_per_child", Field<MyData>(p => p.value))
                        && new MinAggregation("min_per_child", Field<MyData>(p => p.value))
                }
            };

_client.Search<MyData>(sr);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in the documentation you need to add a [static import](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-static) to be able to write the code using the same style

```
using static Nest.Infer;
```

Otherwise you need to use simple `new Field(..)` instantiation

Comment: late nights and thinking VS / Resharper would do all that for me. Thanks

Comment: when you say stated in the documentation - i certainly can't see that anywhere here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/simple-query-string-usage.html

Comment: @WaterBoy check [the tip here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/field-inference.html#nest-infer)